# Problem with validation emails in Apache Commons Validator 1.6

Tags: java, apache-commons, email-validation

I have problem with emails validation in Apache Commons Validatior:

```
john@newman.com => true
john@newman.COM => false
john@newman.Com => false
```

Why does character size matter?

EDIT:
Thank you all for help. Problem wasn't in Apache Commons but in my code.

Comment: @Henry I know, but I don't want to do workarounds for this moment and I want to understand why I have those result.

Comment: It is open source, check the source code. It is telling you why it behaves this way.

Comment: Apache commons email validator already converts the given email to lower case before matching against valid patterns, hence case won't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case does not matter with Apache commons email validator, here is the sample code

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EmailValidator validator = EmailValidator.getInstance();

        if (validator.isValid("john@newman.COM")) {
            System.out.println("Valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested this code with commons-validator-1.6.jar and the emails john@newman.COM, john@newman.Com are valid as per the code.

```
 Output - Valid
```

Apache commons validator internally converts the email to lower case before matching the patterns for a valid email, hence the case will not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.
I tried with your input with `commons-validator-1.6.jar` and all worked for me.

```
EmailValidator valid=EmailValidator.getInstance();
String mail="john@newman.com";
String mail1="john@newman.COM";
String mail2="john@newman.Com";
if(valid.isValid(mail)) {
    System.out.println("Valid Mail : "+mail);
} else {
    System.out.println("InValid Mail : "+mail);
}
```

output :

```
john@newman.com => valid
john@newman.COM => valid
john@newman.Com => valid
```